# Embedded pdf preview inside Microsoft Report Builder 3.0

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am working on creating a Job Traveller for our ERP (Syteline 8.3) with Report Builder 3.0 and SQL 2008 r2 and I need to embed a pdf blueprint into the traveller.

This traveller report will be triggered from within our ERP and it will open as a pdf preview inside the users default browser. The traveller will be printed on standard 8x11 paper and the top half will be dedicated to the blueprint preview.

The data on the traveller will be populated via a stored procedure and our blueprints are stored on a shared file server as pdf documents.

Is there anyway to embed or preview a pdf file inside an SSRS report?

Answer (score 0):

While embedding PDF documents inside of a SSRS report is not supported you can work around this with a little grunt work.

The basic functionality would be to call a SP that uses a CLR library that will open the pdf filename passed in and save it to a temp image. You can then dynamically link the temp image to an image on your report. You will have to figure on these temp file building up and come up with a process to purge them periodically.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34551/Reporting-Services-Embedding-a-PDF-Document) is a link to a similar process outlined above.

If you decide to go this route and have experience with .NET I would take a look at the iTextSharp .NET library. There are many examples on saving PDF's to images.